# Appropriate loss function for unobservable failure time

Tags: survival, loss-functions, censoring

I'm trying to construct a forecast for the failure time of a system.  I have a model for this failure time built from physical understanding of the system. I'd like to be able to quantify the accuracy of my forecast and for that I need a loss function. However, the issue I'm facing is that the true failure time is never observed as the offending part is almost always repaired prior to system failure. That is, my true failure times are right-censored.

Let me give a toy example that illustrates the problem that I'm facing. We have a machine that produces cookies. The number of future cookies the machine can produce is a function of cookie dough yield and wear on the cookie cutter. Currently, bakers must monitor wear on the cookie cutter but this is expensive and honestly the bakers would much rather spend their time experimenting with new recipes. We'd much rather be able to say to the bakers "we expect you can bake 24 more cookies before needing to replace the cookie cutter".

However, letting the cookie cutter break causes many expensive problems so bakers always replace the cutter before it fails. (Unfortunately, each baker has their own preference/risk tolerance so the point at which the cutter is replaced can vary substantially).

Suppose we can make a forecast at time $t_0$ that the machine can bake 24 more cookies and at time $t_1$ the cutter is replaced after having baked 18 cookies.

The only information I have is that the true failure time would be somewhere after 18 cookies. In this situation the forecast falls within the censored interval. However, there are certain situations where I'm certain I've made an error, like if the forecast falls outside the censoring interval. If we forecast 24 cookies and a risky baker runs the machine to produce 27 cookies before replacing the cutter, I've obviously made a mistake.

My question is: what is the appropriate loss function to quantify the forecast accuracy given that the true failure time is unobservable/right censored?

Bonus follow-up question: can we extend this loss function to account for different error costs? Overpredicting how long the machine can run causes very costly repairs when the cutter breaks. Underpredicting is less bad as that would mean we're a little less efficient than we could be.

I've been doing some reading in the survival analysis literature but haven't come across exactly what I need. To be clear, I do not need a survival model for the failure time of the system, I already have one based on physical understanding of the machine. What I desire is loss function to quantify the accuracy of that model.

Comment: The issues of loss function and censoring are separate.  It is difficult to see how they are related.  You have already alluded to the proper loss function: it needs to balance the expense of monitoring wear against the cost of a break during production.  Notice that this makes no reference to censoring!  This makes me wonder whether you might be using "loss function" in some other sense: what exactly would it be?

Comment: I'm using loss function to mean the function which takes in a forecasted failure time and a (possibly right censored) true failure time and assigns a cost to it. In the second example I gave (forecast is 24, true value is after 27), one approach might be to use squared loss between the forecast and censored interval bound giving a cost of (24-27)^2=9.

Comment: But then how would this work in the other example, when I know the true failure time is after 18? If I simply use the interval bound, I'm biasing my costs based on the baker's decision to stop the machine early. My cost would be (18-24)^2 = 36 but arguably I could have been spot on if the ground truth, the unobservable failure time, was actually 24.

Comment: Loss functions (at least in the sense of classical statistics and decision analysis) and censoring don't work like that. Censoring applies to data, not parameters (the true values). The loss would compare the forecasted failure time to the true failure time. After, all, that's what matters in the application.  Analysis of any proposed statistical procedure would concern *expected* loss. You seem to using "loss" in the sense of some quantity to be minimized in order to construct an estimator. I would like to suggest that this might not be a fruitful concept in this setting.

Comment: "The loss would compare the forecasted failure time to the true failure time." Yes, that's what I'm trying to do except that the true failure time is censored. I am not seeking to minimize loss to construct an estimator, as I already have an estimator.

Comment: Perhaps a better way of phrasing the question would be: how is accuracy of a failure time model assessed?

Comment: The answer to that one is--expected loss!  If the bakery owner is coldly rational, they will say that they don't care a bit about the accuracy of your estimator.  What they do care about is how much using it will cost them in the long run.  To appreciate the distinction, suppose that the failure of a machine is catastrophic--it would put the bakery out of business.  Any reasonable estimator is then going to be *extremely* conservative and *inaccurate* (in any scientific sense of the word), because it will avoid risking that eventuality.